# JavaScript: $ is not a function (but it seems like it is)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a weird JavaScript problem that I just cannot understand.

My custom JavaScript file "header.js" uses jQuery. It throws the infamous "**$ is not a function**" error message but I don't understand why. The weird thing is **I'm including jQuery.js** and the code in question seems to have **no problem to bind to jQuery events**. So not having included jQuery is not the problem.

**header.js**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    if ($(document).width() >= 768) {
        var header = false;
        var scrollHandler = function () {
            var scrollTop = $(window).scrollTop(); // line 5 that throws the error
            // more code
        };

        //register function which is called on scroll
        $(window).scroll(scrollHandler);
    }
});
```

**My HTML (with some debug output)**

```
<script src="~/js/vendor/jquery.js"></script>
<script>
    function printTest(str) {
        console.log("test (" + str + "): " + $(".test").length);
    }
</script>
<script>
    printTest("2.1 before header");
</script>

<script src="~/js/header.js"></script>

<script>
    printTest("2.2 after header");
</script>
```

**Output when I load the page**

```
test (2.1 before header): 1
test (2.2 after header): 1
```

But **once I scroll** my console error output shows:

```
TypeError: $ is not a function (line 5 in header.js)
```

Does anyone have an idea why that is? I've analyzed it for hours and I don't understand the reason. Any help/idea/suggestion would be highly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Is `src="~/js/vendor/jquery"` the actual code? If so, does that actually work in a browser?

Comment: Why do you use `"~/js/vendor/jquery.js"` instead of `"./js/vendor/jquery.js"` or `"/js/vendor/jquery.js"`?

Comment: The only real possibility here is that something you're including is assigning to `$` after the main page load is complete. So you'll want to find that and...stop it doing that.

Comment: `~` means home directory in UNIX systems. That's fine, it's not a wrong code.

Comment: I tried to use `~` in Ubuntu Chrome. it is not work for me :) All request is look like `http://test/~/jquery.js` for me which is wrong in Ubuntu Chrome (404 response).

Comment: @MarcosPérezGude: It would be if the file were being loaded from a server. It's okay if loading it from `file://` (but doing that is generally a poor way to work on web pages, browsers do things slightly differently with `file://` pages vs. ones loaded from servers). Of course, for all we know, the OP's got a server configured to understand `~` in relative URLs.

Comment: Post what comes after your second `printTest()` call, at least whatever subsequent `<script>` tags there are.

Comment: Are you using any libraries other than jQuery? Do they redefine `$`?

Comment: Could your jQuery potentially be getting loaded in no-conflict mode? Have you tried injecting the $ using jQuery(document).ready(function ($) { ... }); ? According to http://www.pauljoyceuk.com/codex/2011/jquery-is-not-a-function/   wordpress loads jQuery in no-conflict mode by default, so you have to manually override that setting with the code above. The article is from 2011, but may still be relevant

Comment: Thank you guys for your help. Sorry for the confusion.
Background: I'm running this website using Sitecore. After the jQuery include there are more custom JavaScript file I include. I'm pretty new to Sitecore and JS development. I'm checking your hints.

Comment: @RolandK did you resolve the issue?

Comment: @stackErr I'm still looking for a solution. I've checked the other JavaScript files looking if some of them overrides jQuery's $ function. I was suspecting they might but I don't see how any JavaScript file I include causes a conflict.

Comment: So where is the onscroll code at? I think we need to see your header code.

Comment: @epascarello Do you mean the code I posted in my answer? There I bind on the jQuery scroll event.

Comment: I'm still confused how the jQuery scroll and document.ready can trigger but then the $ is undefined. How is this possible?

Comment: is there a way you would post what is on line#5 of header.js ?

Comment: @82Tuskers It's in the first code block in my question. There is a code comment next to it.

Comment: can you please include your other script includes please .. if not all the significant ones .. thanks !

Comment: `$(document).ready(function ($) {...` (added `$` to args) will fix your problem, but you should still try to figure out what is overriding it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so if you have the same problem here is how I solved it.

The problem was a conflict with require.js. Require.js comes automatically with a module in Sitecore. At first I was not aware that require.js was causing this conflict because when I checked the JavaScript file I was looking for some override of $. What I didn't know at this point was that require.js also has a configuration file that includes its own version of jQuery.

I solved it by removing require.js (and adding the dependencies that it brought manually to my page).

Answer (score 0):

I possibly have a workaround. Its not the exact answer you seek. But can you check if putting the scroll handler's definition outside the document ready works for you ? 
Please try as follows:

```
var scrollHandler = function() {
    var scrollTop = $(window).scrollTop(); // line 5 that throws the error
    // more code
};

$(document).ready(function() {
    if ($(document).width() >= 768) {
        var header = false;
        //register function which is called on scroll
        $(window).scroll(scrollHandler);
    }
});
```

If this does not work too then there is something overriding your $ definition. Can you tell us if this works in your code ?